# What's the usage of org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0

As you can see in the title , I'd appreciate it if somebody can tell the usage of the Class .

There's a inside enum Type ,how to use it?

```
public static enum Type {

        BETWEEN(2, "IsBetween", "Between"), IS_NOT_NULL(0, "IsNotNull", "NotNull"), IS_NULL(0, "IsNull", "Null"), LESS_THAN(
                "IsLessThan", "LessThan"), LESS_THAN_EQUAL("IsLessThanEqual", "LessThanEqual"), GREATER_THAN("IsGreaterThan",
                "GreaterThan"), GREATER_THAN_EQUAL("IsGreaterThanEqual", "GreaterThanEqual"), BEFORE("IsBefore", "Before"), AFTER(
                "IsAfter", "After"), NOT_LIKE("IsNotLike", "NotLike"), LIKE("IsLike", "Like"), STARTING_WITH("IsStartingWith",
                "StartingWith", "StartsWith"), ENDING_WITH("IsEndingWith", "EndingWith", "EndsWith"), NOT_CONTAINING(
                "IsNotContaining", "NotContaining", "NotContains"), CONTAINING("IsContaining", "Containing", "Contains"), NOT_IN(
                "IsNotIn", "NotIn"), IN("IsIn", "In"), NEAR("IsNear", "Near"), WITHIN("IsWithin", "Within"), REGEX(
                "MatchesRegex", "Matches", "Regex"), EXISTS(0, "Exists"), TRUE(0, "IsTrue", "True"), FALSE(0, "IsFalse",
                "False"), NEGATING_SIMPLE_PROPERTY("IsNot", "Not"), SIMPLE_PROPERTY("Is", "Equals");

        // Need to list them again explicitly as the order is important
        // (esp. for IS_NULL, IS_NOT_NULL)
        private static final List<Part.Type> ALL = Arrays.asList(IS_NOT_NULL, IS_NULL, BETWEEN, LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_EQUAL,
                GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_EQUAL, BEFORE, AFTER, NOT_LIKE, LIKE, STARTING_WITH, ENDING_WITH, NOT_CONTAINING,
                CONTAINING, NOT_IN, IN, NEAR, WITHIN, REGEX, EXISTS, TRUE, FALSE, NEGATING_SIMPLE_PROPERTY, SIMPLE_PROPERTY);
...}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use this? It is internal to Spring Data JPA and you shouldn't use it in your application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Part` is internal to Spring Data. It is not intended to be used by client code. So if you don't implement your own Spring Data Modul you shouldn't use it at all nor anything inside it.

A `Part` is basically an element of an AST that will probably result in an element of a where clause or equivalent depending on the store in use.

E.g. if you have a method `findByNameAndDobBetween(String, Date, Date)` parsing the method name will result in two parts. One for the *name* condition and one for the *DOB between* condition.

The type enum lists all the different types of conditions that are possible. 
The parameters of the elements are the number of method arguments required and (possibly multiple) `String`s that identify this type inside a method name.